# lapply sobre dataframe filtrado con dplyr

Tags: r, r-dplyr

soy algo novato en dplyr y r.

Actualmente estoy trabajando con un dataframe (df) con las siguientes caracteristicas:

- `ips2_4` = dataframe con 8 variables numericas y 1 categorica
- `ips2_4$caracteristiks` = variable categorica con 4 niveles (control, nash, obeso, fibrosis)

Lo que me gustaría hacer es:

- Aplicar `filter` para seleccionar solo ciertas observaciones dentro del dataframe.
- Sobre el df ya filtrado usar `lapply` y la funcion `wilcox.test`, el codigo que describe lo que busco es el siguiente:

  `ips2_4%>%filter(caracteristiks %in% ("control","NASH"))%>lapply(function(x{wilcox.test(x~ips2_4$caracteristiks)})`

Sin embargo recibo este error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ ips2_4$caracteristiks) : variable lengths differ (found for 'ips2_4$caracteristiks')
```

Por lo que imagino que al momento de ejecutar `wilcox.test(x~ips2_4$caracteristiks)` toma como referencia la variable inicial del df sin filtrar??

Hay alguna forma de hacer que la `wilcox.test(x~ips2_4$caracteristiks)` tome como base los datos del df ya filtrado?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Luis,

hay un par de problemas de sintaxis con el código que das como ejemplo. El `%>` de antes de `lapply()` debería ser `%>%`. Además en `lapply(function(x{wilcox.test(x~ips2_4$caracteristiks)})` se debería ver más o menos así

```
lapply(function(x) {wilcox.test(x~ips2_4$caracteristiks})
```

Con el paréntesis cerrado después de `(x`

De todos modo se entiende la idea y, en efecto, el problema que te reporta el es de diferencia de largos. Lo que ocurre es que `ips2_4$caracteristiks` tiene el largo del data.frame original mientras `x` tiene el largo del data.frame filtrado.

La forma más simple es hacer primero el filtro, asignar nombre al objeto filtrado y después hacer lo test.

Como no sé cuales son tus datos va un ejemplo con los datos `mtcars`

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl %in% c(8, 6)) -> carros

carros %>% 
    lapply(function(x) {
      wilcox.test(x~carros$cyl)}
      )
```

La prueba de Wilcox tiene muchas variantes (por pares, independientes, con diferentes distribuciones de nulidad). Te sugiero revisar la documentación para ver cuál es la que aplica a tu problema.

Aunque no conozco el problema en el que estás trabajando en general no es buena práctica hacer múltiples pruebas independientes sobre un data set. Aumenta mucho la probabilidad de obtener falsos positivos, ya que aumenta la cantidad de pruebas de hipótesis y es cuestión de tiempo hasta que aparezca un error tipo I.

Además se trabaja con un supuesto muy fuerte de independencia de las variables de la matriz x entre sí, ya que estás testeando cada una por separado. En este caso un modelo lineal sería una alternativa, ya que estima las diferencias de medias en la media de las demás variables y te da un nivel básico de control. Hay alternativas no paramétricas para este tipo de problemas.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu solucion @mpaladino , entiendo los errores y ahora todo corre tal y como lo esperaba!